# How to make a morphological search?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Good day.

I have query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Firm 
WHERE name LIKE 'АВТОМОБИЛЬ%'
```

Tell me please how use morphological search with this query on MsSQL 2008 ?

Comment: Cab you provide some Data?

Comment: @Luv what Data need ?

Comment: What exactly is a "morphological search"? If you mean that you want to search for different forms of the same word, then [full-text search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx) is included in SQL Server and supports [many different languages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176076.aspx).

Comment: thanks all, i find a solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Declare @find NVarchar(20)='test'

SELECT *
FROM Firm 
WHERE name LIKE '%'+@find+'%' OR phone LIKE '%'+@find+'%'
```

Comment: with `@find...='гвоздя'` i get results `КРЕПЛЕНИЕ (КЛЯЙМЕР) №1 С ГВОЗДЯМИ Д/ПАНЕЛИ ДОСТАВКА СКИДКА`

but me need get result where find word will be main, for ex.: `много гвоздей доставка оптом`

Comment: @TesttestTest if you need a CaseSensitive search you can use Collate with a fitting shema containing _CS_ ... in my country it would be  SELECT *
FROM Firm 
WHERE name LIKE '%'+@find+'%'  Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS  OR phone LIKE '%'+@find+'%'   Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS

Comment: not this need, but main query very good) thanks fo help, i will be use this code)

Answer (score 0):

Just run the below `Query`

```
SELECT *
FROM Firm 
WHERE name LIKE N'АВТОМОБИЛЬ%'
             -- ^ Magical Code
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/04b02/1)**

Comment: not work... see image1 и image2 please: 
**image1** http://testwork.ru/1/1.png
**image2** http://testwork.ru/1/2.png

Comment: I mean what should be your expected output.

Comment: all morphological words with 'АВТОМОБИЛЬ'